# Adding button as lest element in gridview

Tags: java, android, button, gridview

I know how to make every single cell in a gridview into a button, but that's not what I'm after.
I have a gridview that's filled with this adapter.

```
public class TaskAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private Context mContext;

    public TaskAdapter(Context c)
    {
        mContext = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return nThumbsIds.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View sView = convertView;

        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
            sView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.task_square, parent, false);

            TextView tView = (TextView) sView.findViewById(R.id.textView);

            tView.setText(nThumbsIds.get(position));

        }
        return sView;
    }
}
```

And nThumbsIds is filled with Strings whose contents will be different at almost every build.

I want to add a button as the last element of the grid, always after all the Strings. Is there a way?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. If you want to add a button as the last element, can't you just add one to the array?

Comment: It's a String array, and it's constantly changed and can even be empty. It's filled by a database query from the activity, I forgot to mention this is all inside a fragment. I want a button with it's own listener and way to set it's layout if it's possible, not just another String that could get popped. If the query returns null, and the String array is empty, the button will still be there.

Comment: Couldn't you just have a button in your layout that's always below the GridView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

Create Adapter

```
 public class TaskAdapter extends BaseAdapter
        {
            private Context mContext;

            public TaskAdapter(Context c)
            {
                mContext = c;
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount()
            {
                return nThumbsIds.size();
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int position)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return nThumbsIds.get(position);
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return position;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
            {
                TextView tView =null;
                Button tBtn =null;

                LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.task_square, parent, false);

                 tView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_txv);
                 tBtn = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_btn);

                if(position < nThumbsIds.size()-1)
                {
                    tView.setText(nThumbsIds.get(position));
                    tView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    tBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                else
                {
                    tBtn.setText(nThumbsIds.get(position));
                    tView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    tBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                return convertView;
            }
```

Your Grid Item layout xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/grid_item_txv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Smaple"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/grid_item_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="sample"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

GridView in your activity's layout :

```
<GridView
        android:id="@+id/test_grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
    </GridView>
```